# IntelliJ IDEA Menu Popups Close too Quickly

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've had this issue with Intellij for quite some time now where the child menus close instantly after your mouse leaves the parent entity. I made a video showing the menus in Eclipse vs IntelliJ and how eclipse has a bit of a delay when moving your mouse towards the menu making it so you can choose the shortest path to your target, while in intellij you have to slide your mouse along the parent entity until you enter the menu so that it does not close.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOofU_CY1ZE

Is this a issue with IntelliJ it'self? Or is it a setting that can be changed?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's more likely that this is difference in behavior between Swing, which IntelliJ uses for UI and native UI which is used by SWT, which is used by Eclipse. I don't think this is something that can be changed in settings. It would probably be best to create bug/feature request on youtrack.jetbrains.com and attach the video you made. Maybe they can change that behavior in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for that bug report link I couldn't find it myself. I'll leave the question open just incase someone has a solution/workaround. Thanks!

Comment: One more reason to only use hotkeys! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the intellij EAP 15 code named Minerva (142.3553.1).

Yay intellij :D :D